# Is it a bad practice to create a new field just for the search purpose?

Tags: mysql

Every time a user searches, I join 8 tables to get the maximum result. tables like tags, location, author, links, etc.

Is it better to create a new field and have all these information in that field and just make a Match query?

The negative side is: duplicate data, makes updating an article more difficult.

Comment: If retrieving data speed is more important for you than insertion speed, this is not a bad idea. Keeping redundant data for query timing improvements is quite common.

Comment: Couldn't you make a view and search the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. In fact, it is commonly used for large database, precisely to limit JOINs in queries.

Concerning the negative side you mentioned, it does really consist of duplication but the positives it brings on queries, is worth it *(for large database explicitly)*. A surplus column doesn't take so much memory to be frightened of.

As for the updates, it as simple as creating a trigger which updates the columns with its values on each insert/update on the parent table.